# How to do longitudinal analysis of random timepoints of data

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, longitudinal-data-analysis

I'm attempting to do a longitudinal analysis from a dataset collected over a multi-year period, to explore time-of-year effects. The dataset has ~1600 subjects who have data for at least two time points. However, there is no uniformity to the number of timepoints a subject has, or the time of year they were collected. Subject A may have data from March and September, but subject B may have 6 data at 6 timepoints randomly scattered throughout the year. The majority (~60%) have only two timepoints, then it goes up from there, and a handful of subjects have 10+ timepoints.

I did a cross-sectional analysis of 4000 subjects who have only 1 timepoint, and  a sinusoidal regression produced similar results to an ANOVA by month. I've submitted to a couple journals and at least one reviewer each time said that it's a cross sectional study, and despite having 4000 subjects it doesn't prove much, so a longitudinal analysis would be better.

For a longitudinal analysis I've considered doing individual regressions, and then doing a regression on the regression results, co-varying by the number of timepoints that were part of each regression. Is this a reasonable strategy? What other methods could I try for a longitudinal analysis? I'm using R, so any examples in R would be very helpful.